# is it possible to use php accelerators with zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

is it possible to use accelerators such as Memcache, APC, etc on a PHP+ZendFramework application and still have it work without Zend Framework going kaputt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use PHP accelerators such as APC, eAccelerator which cache the PHP byte code (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators). Those type of cache just keep your "PHP scripts" in memory. It won't directly affect Zend Framework.

You can also use Memcache by using Zend_Cache (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.introduction.html). Memcache is generally use to store raw data such as DB result, Page result.

Comment: My understanding is that bytecode caches like APC are especially useful for framework-based apps - like Zend Framework - since framework code changes relatively infrequently.

Comment: When I say "It won't directly affect Zend Framework." I was meaning it will not break Zend Framework code.

Answer (score 0):

I use APC under nginx+php-fpm in production with an ZF app and it works great.
(You can use it under apache as well).
It does provide a big boost, but you might want to setup a cron job to clear the apc cache once a day, after a while in certain conditions the memory gets fragmented and the performance drops a bit.